# i need to get the median of values in array and im stuck

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to make something like this and i cant get it right how many tries i do. i have tried so many ways and at the moment i have got it to show the sum of the items but it skips the name in the beginning of every nested array.

```
           00-08 08-16 16-24 medel
Malmö      12    16    9     12.3
Mariestad  13    15    10    12.7
Stockholm  13    15    13    13.7
Upphärad   14    16    15    15
Göteborg   13    14    12    13 


var tempen = [
  ["", "00-08", "08-16", "16-24"],
  ["Malmö", 12, 16, 9],
  ["Mariestad", 13, 15, 10],
  ["Stockholm", 13, 15, 13],
  ["Upphärad", 14, 16, 15],
  ["Göteborg", 13, 14, 12]
];
var newArray = tempen.slice();
tempen[0].push("medel");

function sum_value(prev_value, next_value, ) {
  return ( prev_value + next_value);
};

for (var i = 1; i < newArray.length; i++) {
  newArray[i].shift();
  var sum = newArray[i].reduce(sum_value);
  newArray[i].push(sum);
}

function printit() {
  var varMyinnerHTML = "<table>";
  for (var i = 0; i < tempen.length; i++) {
    varMyinnerHTML += "<tr>";
    for (var j = 0; j < tempen[i].length; j++) {
      varMyinnerHTML += "<td>" + tempen[i][j] + "</td>";
    }
    varMyinnerHTML += "</tr>";
  }
  document.getElementById("kontainer").innerHTML = varMyinnerHTML;
}
```

any help would be awesome im really bad at this :(

Comment: First, solve the problem. Then write the code. Saves you a lot of time ;)

Comment: tank you but the problem is i cant find how to solve the problem haha tired over 10 ways and most of the times i only get NaN or an error

Comment: Looking at the accepted answer, you want the average, not the median.

Comment: ah yes thank you my english is not so good i'm sorry about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were nearly there! Here's your code with minimal modifications for it to work. The fixes are described in the comments.

The main fixes:

- > but it skips the name in the beginning of every nested array

  When calculating the sum, you had to remove the place name `string` to make sure you don't end up with `NaN`. However, you did so by using `shift`, which removed it from the original array you still needed to render the table. To create a new array of just the numbers, you can use `slice`. This doesn't *mutate* the original array so you can later still access the place name.
- > i have got it to show the sum of the items

  You were only pushing the `sum`, but forgot to divide by the number of values!
- You forgot to close your `<table>` tag

```js
var tempen = [
  ["", "00-08", "08-16", "16-24"],
  ["Malmö", 12, 16, 9],
  ["Mariestad", 13, 15, 10],
  ["Stockholm", 13, 15, 13],
  ["Upphärad", 14, 16, 15],
  ["Göteborg", 13, 14, 12]
];

// We don't need a new array
tempen[0].push("medel");

function sum_value(prev_value, next_value) {
  return (prev_value + next_value);
};


for (var i = 1; i < tempen.length; i++) {

  // Don't delete the place names from the orginal!
  // newArray[i].shift();
  
  // Only skip the place name for the sum
  var numbers = tempen[i].slice(1);
  
  var sum = numbers.reduce(sum_value);
  
  // Here, we compute the average by dividing
  // sum by length:
  var avg = sum / numbers.length;

  // Push the average, not the sum:
  tempen[i].push(avg);
}


function printit() {
  // Add a body
  var varMyinnerHTML = "<table><tbody>";
  
  for (var i = 0; i < tempen.length; i++) {

    varMyinnerHTML += "<tr>";
    for (var j = 0; j < tempen[i].length; j++) {
      varMyinnerHTML += "<td>" + tempen[i][j] + "</td>";
    }
    varMyinnerHTML += "</tr>";
  }
  
  // Close the body and table
  varMyinnerHTML += "</tbody></table>"

  document.getElementById("kontainer").innerHTML = varMyinnerHTML;
}

// Run the code
printit();
```

```html
<div id="kontainer"></div>
```

Comment: another kinda newbie question. if i want to round up the numbers to just 1 decimal how do i do that? i understand i need to use something like 
Math.round( numbers * 10 ) / 10 but im not sure were in the code i should use it

Comment: You want to round the average, so the code should be around the avg variable

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `forEach` for iterating. Nothing is different with arrays and nested arrays.

```js
var tempen = [
  ["", "00-08", "08-16", "16-24"],
  ["Malmö", 12, 16, 9],
  ["Mariestad", 13, 15, 10],
  ["Stockholm", 13, 15, 13],
  ["Upphärad", 14, 16, 15],
  ["Göteborg", 13, 14, 12]
],
  newArr = [];
  
tempen.forEach(function(itm){
  let sum = 0;
  itm.forEach(function(num){
    if(typeof num == 'number') {
      sum += num;
    }
  });
  newArr.push(sum/(itm.length - 1));
});

printit();

function printit() {
  var varMyinnerHTML = "<table>";
  for (var i = 0; i < tempen.length; i++) {
    varMyinnerHTML += "<tr>";
    for (var j = 0; j < tempen[i].length; j++) {
      varMyinnerHTML += "<td>" + tempen[i][j] + "</td>";
    }
    varMyinnerHTML += "<td>" + newArr[i] + "</td>";
    varMyinnerHTML += "</tr>";
  }
  document.getElementById("kontainer").innerHTML = varMyinnerHTML;
}
```

```html
<div id="kontainer"></div>
```